# Stop the nag notification for enabling texts on Hangouts?

Tags: sms, notifications, google-hangouts

Pretty much every time I get a text message, Hangouts gives me an annoying notification asking to handle my text messages (which I don't want to do). Is there a way to disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn it on, then go into Hangouts and turn it off.

Actually I really wanted to write/receive SMS from Hangouts, but it didn't quite work well. Sometimes I could not even reply to the message. So yeah. I disabled it and no nag ever since.

Comment: I'm trying your method at the moment, but it may take a day or two to see if it works!

Comment: It's alright. I got the stupid notifciation again after a Hangouts update. Gotta love Google.

Comment: Hmm, that sucks. I think I'm going to chalk it up to "Google is trying to control my life and will never stop."

Comment: Well, I haven't gotten any annoying notifications since I read your answer, so I'm going to mark it as accepted! It's not permanent, but better than nothing.